# driver pod keeps Running

Tags: scala, apache-spark, kubernetes

I'm running Spark 3.1.1 on Kubernetes in cluster mode with the following command:

```
command:
  - /opt/spark/bin/spark-submit
  - --deploy-mode
  - cluster
  - --name
  - "my_job_name"
  - --master
  - k8s://https://kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local
  - --class
  - $(CLASS)
  - --conf
  - spark.kubernetes.namespace=my-namespace
  - --conf
  - spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=my-driver-sa
  - --conf
  - spark.kubernetes.driver.limit.cores=$(DRIVER_LIMIT_CORES)
  - --conf
  - spark.executor.instances=$(EXECUTOR_INSTANCES)
  - --conf
  - spark.executor.memory=$(EXECUTOR_MEMORY)
  - --conf
  - spark.executor.cores=$(EXECUTOR_CORES)
  - --conf
  - spark.kubernetes.executor.limit.cores=$(EXECUTOR_CORES)
  - --conf
  - spark.kubernetes.container.image=$(CONTAINER_REGISTRY)/$(IMAGE_REPOSITORY):$(TAG)
  - --conf
  - spark.jars.ivy=/tmp/.ivy
  - --conf
  - spark.eventLog.enabled=true
  - --conf
  - spark.eventLog.dir=$(EVENT_LOG_DIR)
  - --conf
  - spark.eventLog.rolling.enabled=true
  - --conf
  - spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider=$(CREDS_PROVIDER)
  - --conf
  - spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl=org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem
  - local://$(APPLICATION_JAR)
  - -s
  - $(APP_ARG_1)
  - -d
  - $(APP_ARG_2)
```

Everything seems to work, driver pod is starting, executors starting as well, doing some job, terminating and I see the last log in the driver:

```
21/05/24 11:29:46 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
```

My problem is that the driver stays in a running state and not terminating after the job is done.

What am I missing?

Comment: any chance that something in u'r app code is keeping it alive? I would add prints to the code just before the program is about to exit.
if u'r still unsure u can add a shutdown hook and see if it triggers - org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager

Comment: Any luck on this? Facing same issue.

Comment: Yes, it was something in my code (statsd client) that prevent the termination of the driver pod

Comment: @ItayB ohh.. in my case the internal thread of spark only not terminating the pod. Tried spark.stop() but no use.

Comment: It happened for a reason (something you did). Try to comment out parts of your code to find it..

Comment: what can be wrong here ? what can i possibly check in code which can result in spark driver pod not exiting ?

Comment: @AviralKumar for me it was an old `statsd` library that report metrics. As soon as I commented out those related lines - the driver terminated. Additionally, this might help too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68698855/1011253

Comment: I got the thread dump of the driver process and found this thread which is a cleanup thread  in WAITING state. org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Statistics$StatisticsDataReferenceCleaner .. can this be an issue ?

Comment: Not sure my friend. I would recommend start commenting out parts of your code until you'll find the problematic line